# How do I combine the Big Query table lists?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I saved it to Big Query with Firebase Analytics.

I want to `SELECT` the events stored in the big query. But the tables are by date.

Is there anyway to `SELECT` events on these tables at once?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`Wildcard Tables`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables) feature

Quick example:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.app_events_*`
```